# month format php

Tags: php

I am just a beginner in php. I am trying to print the array of months using the following code.

```
<?php
$totalmonth=12;
for($startmonth=01; $startmonth<=$totalmonth; $startmonth++)
{
    $montharr[]=$startmonth;
}
print_r($montharr);
?>
```

My result is `Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 2 [2] => 3 [3] => 4 [4] => 5 [5] => 6 [6] => 7 [7] => 8 [8] => 9 [9] => 10 [10] => 11 [11] => 12 )`

I need my result should look like this

```
[0] => 01 [1] => 02
```

How can i do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use str_pad.

```
<?php
$totalmonth=12;
for($startmonth=1; $startmonth<=$totalmonth; $startmonth++)
{
    $montharr[]=str_pad($startmonth, 2, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
}
print_r($montharr);
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use [sprintf](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php) to print it to a string as [zero-padded integers](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php#example-4381).

Example:

```
<?php
  $month = sprintf("%02d", $month);
```

due to the nature of integers, math; PHP (and the majority of all applications) will interpret `(int)01` as `1`. To keep the leading zero, it has to be a string.

Answer (score 0):

PHP has many date functions that will probably serve better solutions to whatever you're trying to achieve, but a very quick and dirty way would be to check if the number is lower then 10 and then prepend a zero:

```
<?php
$totalmonth=12;
for($startmonth=1; $startmonth<=$totalmonth; $startmonth++)
{
    // Check amount
    if($startmonth < 10) {
        $montharr[]='0'.$startmonth;
    } else {
        $montharr[]=$startmonth;
    }
}
print_r($montharr);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

For example `sprintf`: http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php

Answer (score 0):

Use PHP built-in str_pad:

```
<?php
$totalmonth=12;
for($startmonth=01; $startmonth<=$totalmonth; $startmonth++)
{
    $montharr[] = str_pad($startmonth, 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
}
print_r($montharr);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Force that a String is inserted, by implicitly converting it into one:

```
 $montharr[]= "" + $startmonth;
```